# Wordpress - on local setup

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I am getting below error in on my Local wordpress setup after sending form data.
I am using Contact 7 form plugin for inquiry form in my website.

> **Send  There was an error trying to send your message. Please try again later.**

Thanks in Advance and please help me to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

There might be 2 possible causes of this error. You can refer the guide by plugin author which explains it in detail. [Read the guide](https://contactform7.com/faq/after-submitting-the-form-i-get-an-error-message/) and identify the type of error you get and based on that you will need to fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your mail section or try with a different email address.

Answer (score 0):

There could be two causes for this. The first is actual mail server trouble, where email cannot be sent. In this case, the error message would be surrounded with a RED border line. Contact your server admin.

The second possible cause is that the form submission is under suspicion of spam. In this case, the error message would be surrounded with an ORANGE border line.

response message samples[image]

for Reference please follow below link
FAQ > [After submitting the form, I get an error message stating “There was an error trying to send your message.” What is wrong?](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/there-was-an-error-trying-to-send-your-message-please-try-again-later-35/)

Answer (score 0):

**Contact 7 plugin  work on live** .Its **does not work on local** so its showing  the  the error message "**There was an error trying to send your message.”**  after submitting the form in local.

Try it on **live** it will work.